# Unable to get auth token from twitter

Tags: twitter, ionic3

I am trying to get auth token from twitter api https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token but getting 403 forbidden issue.
My credentials(API Key and API Secret key) are right and verified.

I tried that on postman by converting online my credentials in base64.

```
this.twitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";

var combined = encodeURIComponent(this.consumerKey) + ":" + encodeURIComponent(this.consumerSecret);


base64Encoded = btoa(combined);
      // Get the token
      this.http.post(this.twitterTokenURL, { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Encoded, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' }, "grant_type=client_credentials").
        map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data) => {
          this.authorization = data;
          console.log(data);
          if (data && data.token_type && data.token_type === "bearer") {
            //resolve(data)
          }
          resolve(this.data);
        })
```

Comment: Not quiet sure, but do you have to use encodeURIComponent on your consumerKey and Secret?

Comment: I did try after removing that but it didn't helped.